# Installation of R packages in Termux app

Tags: applications, installation, terminal

I having trouble installing  'curl'  , a R package in Termux app. Without that, I can not install the much acclaimed tidyverse package in R. Whenever I tried to install 'curl', it spits out configuration error with  libcurl not found but I checked both curl and libcurl is installed from the terminal. I also tried the suggestion that came along the error message by setting directories in R CMD command but it did not work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed by first installing libcurl-dev from the command line, before running R:

```
$ pkg install libcurl-dev
```